# How can I make my primary DNS take priority over other servers?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

*Note - I believe my title is the way it's meant to be...*

I used dnsmasq on my server and it sets DNS (via DHCP) to clients as:

```
192.168.2.1 (local server)
ISP DNS 1
ISP DNS 2
```

This at least works - in my Ubuntu client `sudo nmcli dev list | grep DNS` gives

```
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.2.1 (local)
IP4.DNS[2]:                             122.56.237.1 (ISP 1)
IP4.DNS[3]:                             210.55.111.1 (ISP 2)
```

However, if I execute `ping mail.mydomain.org` it returns the external internet address instead of the local network.

`nslookup` shows that Ubuntu's network manager is at work (matching `nmcli` above), and states the external IP for my domain is Non-Authoritative. 
When I change to `server 192.168.2.1`, the search just gives me the local IP.

My (client's) resolve.conf ends up with

```
nameserver 172.20.1.153
nameserver 172.20.1.6
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Is the primary at the bottom? It's what nslookup seems to use...

So how can this happen? What should I do to fix it? (I certainly want to keep a secondary DNS). I've tried just having the local DNS server, but dnsmasq can't seem to forward anything no matter what config I change (the documentation isn't helpful either, since it seems that it should "just forward" by default).

And note that while my analysis is on Ubuntu, the same is happening on a Mac too.

Comment: I disabled the secondary and ternary DNS servers in my DHCP and got a strange result. *DNS lookup took a second when only the Primary was available*. Again, when I change nslookup to talk to the Primary directly it's 2ms.

Comment: What's in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: @garethTheRed Updated

Comment: Your `resolv.conf` should be the same as `nmcli`.  Linux's resolver will be using `resolv.conf` as the authoritive list of resolvers, therefore the issue is why Network Manager isn't updating `resolv.conf`. Does `resolv.conf` have a remark to the effect that it was generated by NetworkManager?

Comment: @garethTheRed It most certainly does (I just omitted that because I _thought_ it was what you wanted). The question is, where is network manager getting these 172.20 addresses from? They're in the private spaces, and really slow down my resolution :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither DNS resolver lists nor `NS` record sets are intrinsically ordered, so there is no "primary". Clients are free to query whichever one they want in whichever order they want. For resolvers specifically, clients *might* default to using the servers in the same order as they were given to the client, but, as you've discovered, they also might not.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this, IMO, is to have your local resolver also do recursive lookups. You configure your local resolver with the IPs of your ISPs' resolvers, and then configure all your clients with only the local one. It'll respond with its own information if it has it, and the timing penalty for going via a server on the LAN is insignificant.